# The curve of expansion $(a+b)^n$

Tags: geometry, binomial-coefficients, logarithms

I have read   very interesting article about binomial   form $(a+b)^n$,article says that if we expand $(a+b)^n$ and arrange it,then we can see very beautiful shape,in particular,if we make $n$ bigger and  bigger,the shape gets nearer and nearer to the graph of $y = -(x\log x + (1 - x)\log(1 - x))$, where the base of the logarithm is $10$.
i am interested  why is so and how also,article says that  To prove this fact we only need Sterling's formula and the binomial theorem.please help me  to clarify  what is  this fact happened?thanks

Comment: What article is this?

Comment: it was on wolfram site unfortunately i have opened other links and lost it, i am searching now

Comment: Please do mention the link when you find it, to make things easier for you and potential answerers.

Comment: @dato, check your browser history

Comment: @dato: Is this your article?: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5743/

Comment: yes yes exactly it is ,sorry i was out,it is this article which i have mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is stated a bit more clearly [here](http://www.mi.sanu.ac.rs/vismath/miyadera/999/node4.html). It's done in R. Miyadera and Y. Kotera, Una Bella Curva Che Troviamo in Connessione con lo Sviluppo di Archimede 2/2005, which I haven't been able to find on the web. The coefficients when you multiply out $(a+b)^n$ are the binomial coefficients $n\choose r$, $r=0,1,\dots,n$. The curve is formed by the *lengths* of these coefficients, which is to say by the numbers $\log_{10}{n\choose r}$ (roughly). The coefficients themselves converge, on division by $2^n$, to the normal distribution, which is related to $e^{-x^2}$. If you replace node4 with node3 in the link you'll see Stirling (note spelling) used to prove a similar result.